# Find and replace confined to a specific column (one-liner)

Tags: regex, string, perl

Is there a way (in a one-liner) to confine find and replace to within a specific column of a tab-delimited .txt file?

For example:

```
perl -pe 's/A/B/g;'
```

But which only finds and replaces 'A' with 'B' within column-2 and ignores all other instances of A, converting this:

```
1   A   A2
2   A   A
3   B   B1
4   A   B
5   A   A
6   B   A3
7   A   A
8   C   A
9   E   B
10  D   B
11  A   C6
12  A   G
13  B   L
14  A   E
15  B   A
16  A   A
```

Into:

```
1   B   A2
2   B   A
3   B   B1
4   B   B
5   B   A
6   B   A3
7   B   A
8   C   A
9   E   B
10  D   B
11  B   C6
12  B   G
13  B   L
14  B   E
15  B   A
16  B   A
```

Comment: Almost certainly. Sample data would help massively though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this will transform the second field of a tab separated row.

```
perl -lne '@row = split /\t/; $row[1] =~ s/A/B/; print join ( "\t", @row );'
```

Comment: This is returning `Substitution replacement not terminated at -e line 1.` What is causing that?

Comment: A missing `/`. Edited

Comment: It now runs without error but only acts on the first line of the .txt file - or at least only replaces the first 'A' it finds in column-2.

Comment: Sorry - issues with the .txt file caused by hidden characters. Now it works.

Comment: Given you don't have any other whitespace, you could probably just `split;` which defaults to any whitespace.

Comment: You can shorten that up a bit by using the `-a` flag: `perl -anE '$F[1] =~ s/A/B/; say join "\t", @F' in.txt`. Search for it in [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html)

Comment: @stevieb Thanks! Is there a shorter way to perform multiple search/replacements other than simply chaining them together e.g. `perl -anE '$F[1] =~ s/A/B/; $F[1] =~ s/D/F/; say join "\t", @F'`?

Comment: You could say `$F[1] =~ tr/AD/BF/;`

Answer (score 2):

You can write this:

```
perl -lane '$F[1]=~tr/A/B/;print join("\t", @F)' file
```

Answer (score 1):

#### A sed one-liner

```
$ sed 'h;s/^.*\t\(.*\)\t.*$/\1/;y/A/B/;G;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\t\).*\(\t.*\)/\2\1\3/' infile
1       B       A2
2       B       A
3       B       B1
4       B       B
5       B       A
6       B       A3
7       B       A
8       C       A
9       E       B
10      D       B
11      B       C6
12      B       G
13      B       L
14      B       E
15      B       A
16      B       A
```

Explained:

```
# Copy pattern space to hold space
h

# Remove first and third column from pattern space
s/^.*\t\(.*\)\t.*$/\1/

# Transliterate A to B (can use s/// for more complex substitutions)
y/A/B/

# Append hold space to pattern space
G

# Replace second column with transliterated value
s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\t\).*\(\t.*\)/\2\1\3/
```

#### A sed-free alternative

```
$ paste <(cut -f 1 infile) <(cut -f 2 infile | tr A B) <(cut -f 3 infile)
```

This uses `paste` , `cut` and `tr` with process substitution. The `tr` can of course be replaced by a sed substitution for more complex changes.